# Fetching values from EditText (Some of which are generated Dynamic) Boxes in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, textwatcher

Problem scenario:

I have a view pager in which I have divided a form in different tabs. 
Now one of the tabs looks like:

[image]

The XML for one row being:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:tag="lin_email_container">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_linear"
                    android:tag="email_sub_container"
                    android:weightSum="5">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/email_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view3"
                        android:layout_width="0.3dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#D3D3D3" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_emailadd"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add_to_queue" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

On press of the + icon at the extreme right, which is an ImageView with `id = btn_emailadd` I add one more similar control, its like the good old add more field and looks like this after added:

[image]

As is visible above, I added one email field.

**The Problem**
In order to get values from these dynamic EditTexts I need to implement a textwatcher for all. I am also implementing tags for views, but I am afraid I am not able to maintain unique tags while adding content. This is how I add content:

```
public void addView(LinearLayout container, String[] spin_array, String hint) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_content, null);

        Spinner spin_dynamic = (Spinner) addView.findViewById(R.id.email_spinner1);
        EditText edt_dynamic = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_email1);
        ImageView remove_dynamic = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);
        LinearLayout sub_layout = (LinearLayout) addView.findViewById(R.id.sub_layout);

        edt_dynamic.setHint(hint);
        setUpSpinners(spin_array, spin_dynamic);
        edt_dynamic.setTag(container.getTag() + "edt_text" + container.getChildCount());


        container.indexOfChild(edt_dynamic);
        // get height from dimens
        int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.lin_height);
        // set this height
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);

        // we are only concerned about top margin here.
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.topMargin), 0, 0);
        container.addView(addView, 1, layoutParams);

        remove_dynamic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);

            }
        });

    }
```

So it melts down to, without having any solid Id's and without any solig tags, how can I implement textwatchers, that too to a dynamic content.

The easiest solution I could find to this problem is to use a Parent traversal mechanism, however this would not work in a View Pager, as there is no event I can run this code on:

```
public void traverseLinearLayout(LinearLayout layout) {
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof LinearLayout) {
                traverseLinearLayout((LinearLayout) v);
            }
            if (v instanceof EditText) {
                System.out.println(v.getTag());
                //Get Edit Text value here
            }

            if (v instanceof Spinner) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have tags on the `Parent Layout:`

`android:id="@+id/email_container"`

This solves half of your problem. Now make a generic Class which implements a TextWatcher:

```
public class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    public View view;

    public GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //do nothing
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //do nothing
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        System.out.println(view.getTag());
    }
}
```

When you create the view dynamically, you just need to know if the `EditText` is for email or for any other form field like: web, phone, messenger etc. You can use `.contains` or `.equals` methods for the same.

This is a bit hacky but now you can easily do something like:

```
 edt_dynamic.setTag(container.getTag() + "edt_text" + new Date());
 edt_dynamic.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(edt_dynamic));
```

Beware to replace `new Date()` with something having a nanosecond precision.

In the Textwatcher, you can add key value pairs to a `Map`, depending on the scenario. Make sure you remove the Key, Value (from the Map) when `X` for removing `EditText` is pressed.